# Connect Oracle database to Grails 3

Tags: oracle, grails

I am trying to use an Oracle database to a Grails project. I work with the command line tool.

So far:

- I have put the ojdb6 into a lib directory I had to create myself, at the root of my application
- I modified application.yml as follow:

  ```
  dataSource:
      pooled: true
      jmxExport: true
      driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      username: usrname
      password: pwd

  environments:
      development:
          dataSource:
              dbCreate: create-drop
              url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//url:port/db
      test:
          dataSource:
              dbCreate: update
              url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//url:port/db
      production:
          dataSource:
              dbCreate: update
              url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//url:port/db
              properties:
                  jmxEnabled: true
                  initialSize: 5
                  maxActive: 50
                  minIdle: 5
                  maxIdle: 25
                  maxWait: 10000
                  maxAge: 600000
                  timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                  minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                  validationQuery: SELECT 1
                  validationQueryTimeout: 3
                  validationInterval: 15000
                  testOnBorrow: true
                  testWhileIdle: true
                  testOnReturn: false
                  jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                  defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
  ```
- I also created a domain-class with an Integer attribute, just to give it a try.

However, it doesn't seem to work. I get a huge error message that doesn't even fit in my command window. When I use --stacktrace, the first message is "Failed to start server".

I've been trying to solve this problem for three days, any idea/comment will be welcome. Thank you kindly.

Side note: everythink works perfectly when I use the default database, not changing anything in the configuration.

Comment: Have you substituted the JDBC URL (`jdbc:oracle:thin:@//url:port/db`) or do you really use that value?

Comment: I don't use url:port/db. I use the information regarding the database I have to connect to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below, it should work. if it doesn't post the stack trace. below snippet worked for me.

**Add dependency:**
    runtime 'oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4.0'

**Changes in application.yml:**

```
environments:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:


development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: validate
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1521:xx
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        username: "XXXXXX"
        password: "XXXXXX"
        properties:
           ***: **
           ***: **
test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        properties:
            jmxEnabled: true
            initialSize: 5
            maxActive: 50
            minIdle: 5
            maxIdle: 25
            maxWait: 10000
            maxAge: 600000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
            validationQueryTimeout: 3
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: false
            jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
            defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe it might work; I can't test it anymore though since I don't work on this project anymore (and therefore I don't have any access to the code). I'll still validate your answer though because i believe it might be of some use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle DB the validation statement (property validationQuery: SELECT 1) should be something like:

`"SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"`

Oracle does not support `SELECT 1`

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue recently and in my case it was due to using a format that did not match with my Oracle database configuration; this is what I found:

---

If your database uses an **SID**, your url should be in the form:

`url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:port:sid`,

e.g. `url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.44:1521:testdb`

---

If your database uses a **Service Name**, your url should be in the form:

`url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//url:port/servicename`

e.g. `url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/testdb`

---

Hope this helps